# Celery periodic tasks not triggering

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am working in an application based on **Django 1.6**, **Celery 3.0.24**, **djcelery 3.0.23**. I have to sent some mail periodically each month. I ran the **celeryd**, **celerybeat** and **celerycam** using **supervisor**. I added entries in **PeriodicTask table of djcelery module**(tasks given in tasks.py file). But the t**asks doesn't seem to execute at the specified time**. Have I missed something while configuring for periodic tasks? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you haven't provided any code, I will just try to write how I did the similar task you written about. My project structure was like this:

```
project
  -settings.py
  -manage.py
  -app
    -__init__py
    -celery.py
    -tasks.py
    -views.py
    -models.py
```

I configured celery in `settings.py` like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
BROKER_URL = 'pyamqp://guest:guest@wlocalhost:5672//' #read docs
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('app.tasks', )
from celery.schedules import crontab
from datetime import timedelta

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'schedule-name': { 
                        'task': 'app.tasks',  # example: 'files.tasks.cleanup'
                        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
                        },
    }
```

Code of `celery.py` in app directory:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
import django
from django.conf import settings
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')
app = Celery('blackwidow.communication.email_sending_method')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend',
    )
@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

And updated the `__init__.py` file within that directory:–

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import app as celery_app
```

Code of the `tasks.py` in `app` directory:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import datetime
from celery.task.base import periodic_task
from django.core.mail import send_mail

@periodic_task(run_every=datetime.timedelta(seconds=30))
def email_sending_method():
        send_mail('subject', 'body', 'from_me@admin.com' , ['to_me@admin.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

I added respective credentials/configurations for sending mail in `settings.py`, and then ran this piece of code in command prompt:–

```
celery -A app worker -B -l info             #I think you missed this.
```

And that should do the trick, it will send mail after every 30 seconds.